# How many ImageTargets can be saved in one DataSet in Vuforia TargetManager?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm writing `AugmentedReality` application using `Vuforia` for `Unity3d` plugin. I have to store thousands of `ImageTargets` in one `DataSet` (1 ImageTarget =  1 real user in my application).

I will create application, which will recognize user id by custom avatar. Avatar will be uploaded by user on my website, then I will create `DataSet` (update existing) with new avatar, and attach new `DataSet` to `ImageTargets` at runtime.

Is there a limit for `ImageTargets DataSet`?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found answer on my own question:

"*Applications can use multiple device databases simultaneously. You are only limited to activate* **100 targets** *in total* **at the same time**, *independent of how many loaded device databases*"

[Loading multiple device databases and activating one](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/loading-multiple-device-databases-and-activating-one)